# Run time error when converting template type to interface type in c#

Tags: c#, generics

I'm attempting to convert Java code to C# but I'm running into a problem when it comes to generic casts.

I have an interface type called Copyable which exposes the following method...

```
interface Copyable { void copyTo(Copyable target); }
```

And an AtomicObject type which takes as a parameter a generic type which is restricted to implement the Copyable interface...

```
class AtomicObject<T> where T : class, Copyable {
    public T openRead();
```

I store AtomicObjects in a Dictionary of object types, but I need to cast the objects back to AtomicObjects to call the "openRead" method that is specific to the AtomicObject class...

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> entry in dict)
{
    AtomicObject<Copyable> obj = (AtomicObject<Copyable>)entry.Key;
    Copyable dest = (Copyable)obj.openRead();//get the destination
}
```

I have implemented a ListNode type which plays the role of the parameter for the AtomicObject...

```
class ListNode<T> : Copyable
AtomicObject<ListNode<string>> atomic = new AtomicObject<ListNode<string>>();
```

I can compile this code, but when I run this program it produces an "InvalidCastException" because the runtime system is unable to convert an object of type...

```
AtomicObject<ListNode<string>>
```

to...

```
AtomicObject<Copyable>.
```

Yet the ListNode is of type Copyable. Can anyone explain why this cannot be cast correctly? Most importantly, can anyone suggest a fix which does not rely on the Dictionary or the foreach loop having to know what type of parameter a ListNode contains? For example, in Java I could have done...

```
AtomicObject<?> obj = (AtomicObject<?>)entry.Key;
```

But this is not possible in C-Sharp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do that, because you need covariance, and classes can't be covariant.

So you'll have to extract interface from your `AtomicObject`:

```
interface IAtomicObject<out T> where T : class, Copyable
{
    public T openRead();
}
```

(please note `out` in generic declaration), and make your `AtomicObject` class implement it.

After that you should be able to run following code

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> entry in dict)
{
    IAtomicObject<Copyable> obj = (IAtomicObject<Copyable>)entry.Key;
    Copyable dest = obj.openRead();
}
```

Also please note that .net standards recommend prefixing interface names with I.

Comment: I haven't run through the co/contra variance stuff recently - does this mean that `AtomicObject` can no longer take a generic parameter? I can't get that working in my small LINQPad sample.

Comment: It still can. `class AtomicObject<T>: IAtomicObject<T>`

Comment: Yeah the problem was I was trying `AtomicObject<Copyable> blah = new AtomicObject<ListNode<string>>();` when I needed to write  `IAtomicObject<Copyable> blah = new AtomicObject<ListNode<string>>();`

Comment: Got it, that seems to have fixed the problem now. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are running into is due to the difference in how generics are implemented in C# vs. Java.  Java implements generics using type erasure- that is, an `AtomicObject<Anything>` is effectively an `AtomicObject<Object>` at runtime.  In C# that isn't the case- generics are implemented using reified types, and as such maintain their type parameterization at runtime.  In C#, an `AtomicObject<Whatever>` is always an `AtomicObject<Whatever>`, and never an `AtomicObject<SomethingElse>` (unless AtomicObject is an interface- see generic variance).

What you can do is type-parameterize the method containing your loop:

(Note- interfaces in C# should start with a capital I by convention.  I have renamed your Copyable as such)

I think the following should do what you are after.  Note I have note tested this code:

```
public void DoSomething<TObj>(IEnumerable<AtomicObject<TObj>, Object> dict) 
    where TObj : ICopyable {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<AtomicObject<TObj>, Object> entry in dict)
    {
        ICopyable dest = entry.Key.openRead();
        // Whatever...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had looked at making the methods generic but I can't know the type parameter of the ListNode when I create the dictionary. The approach suggested by Serg Rogovtsev seems the best option.